# How to disable favicon fetching in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, favicon, chromium

How can I tell chrome *not to fetch* any favicon.ico files from a webserver? For web development and debugging, I find this very annoying when I read server side logs. Loading the favicon is also bias when measuring and optimizing my page load times so I want to completely disabled it on the *client* side in chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this Chrome extension [I hate your favicon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/i-hate-your-favicon/laggbmpbikikiablknnppgglelkncemk), or build your own one, which utilizes [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) module and trap all outgoing requests for favicons.

Also you could possibly set up one of ad blocking extensions to do the same job.

P.S. You can read discussion about whether to consider this as a bug, or feature in the [issue 39402](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402) at Chromium porject, I think it applies to Chrome as well. And it seems there will be no easy way to turn this behaviour off via options in the near future.

Comment: That extension doesn't exist anymore :/